# Is there a problem with my data set for language identification using sklearn?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, feature-extraction, text-classification

I've trained my language identification model on huge training data set for 53 languages. For some languages the precision is spot on but some languages are failing pretty bad, English is one of them. This leads me to think that data-set is still messed up.

I've under-sampled the data to 500 records, removed special characters, extra spaces and different punctuation from the text and have limited the length of the text field to 140 chars. The data set for English after clean up looks like this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lv4ZqTPUCRV2s4G9-LWlXXVxtpW2s9Hb/view

Sadly, the precision is barely .5. Some of the lines still contains different language texts, however, I'm not sure how to take care of this.

Also, I'm using TFIidfVectorizer with ngram_range of 1 to 3 to normalize the text feature and logistic regression classifier on top of that. I've also tried MultinomilaNB but in vain. Below is my code:

```
y_resampled , x_resampled = under_sample(x, y)

x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = model_selection.train_test_split(x_resampled, y_resampled, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

vectorizer = feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 3), analyzer='char')

pipe = pipeline.Pipeline([
        ('vectorizer', vectorizer),
        ('clf', linear_model.LogisticRegression())])

# pipe = pipeline.Pipeline([
#     ('vectorizer', vectorizer),
#     ('clf', SGDClassifier())
# ])
pipe.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_predicted = pipe.predict(x_val)

print(metrics.classification_report(y_val, y_predicted, target_names=label_names))
```

Here's the classification report:

```
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

      ar       0.96      0.95      0.95       209
      az       0.95      0.77      0.85       189
      be       0.88      0.85      0.86       235
      bg       0.77      0.79      0.78       199
      ca       0.65      0.62      0.63       199
      ce       0.85      0.76      0.80       109
     ceb       0.73      0.47      0.57        51
      cs       0.84      0.72      0.78       210
      da       0.55      0.56      0.56       202
      de       0.67      0.79      0.73       214
      el       0.96      0.92      0.94       203
      en       0.44      0.68      0.53       208
      eo       0.71      0.70      0.71       181
      es       0.66      0.54      0.60       204
      et       0.73      0.84      0.78       150
      eu       0.77      0.84      0.81       195
      fa       0.92      0.88      0.90       212
      fi       0.79      0.83      0.81       212
      fr       0.65      0.74      0.69       212
      gl       0.51      0.60      0.55       178
      he       1.00      0.97      0.98       220
      hi       1.00      0.89      0.94       186
      hr       0.41      0.38      0.39       199
      hu       0.86      0.88      0.87       204
      hy       0.99      0.91      0.95       211
      id       0.46      0.40      0.43       211
      it       0.58      0.75      0.65       185
      ja       0.97      0.87      0.92       215
      ka       0.99      0.94      0.97       198
      kk       0.93      0.82      0.87       208
      ko       0.98      0.94      0.96       207
      la       0.54      0.70      0.61       185
   lorem       0.88      0.94      0.91       192
      lt       0.81      0.88      0.84       184
      ms       0.42      0.49      0.45       181
      nl       0.69      0.76      0.72       202
      nn       0.59      0.54      0.56       209
      no       0.49      0.46      0.47       197
      pl       0.70      0.78      0.74       196
      pt       0.57      0.52      0.54       185
      ro       0.77      0.81      0.79       219
      ru       0.67      0.74      0.70       180
      sh       0.54      0.39      0.45       205
      sk       0.73      0.68      0.70       179
      sl       0.55      0.58      0.57       173
      sr       0.84      0.88      0.86       192
      sv       0.63      0.59      0.61       211
      th       1.00      0.88      0.94       216
      tr       0.74      0.67      0.70       196
      uk       0.86      0.74      0.80       210
      ur       0.95      0.87      0.91       159
      uz       0.75      0.79      0.77       162
      vi       0.84      0.83      0.83       186
      vo       1.00      0.51      0.68        70
     war       0.73      0.69      0.71       100
      zh       0.75      0.91      0.82       197

micro avg       0.74      0.74      0.74     10602
macro avg       0.75      0.74      0.74     10602
weighted avg       0.75      0.74      0.75     10602
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your results are very good. Your question has broad possibility. I am pointing some of them.

There is no `golden rule` to the selection of model in `machine learning`. You can try different models and look for the reason `why one is working and other not?`. Which build experience, to select these model.

`The prediction of these model depend on features`. There is possibility that while `undersampling`, you are losing lots of good information(even for english), even `some-times special characters, punctualtions` has valuable information. You can try that too.

But, again your results are good. But you can try other models too, and pick which fits best.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing I can think of is to allow a certain number, like 40, of the most common special characters. Some of them instantly give away the language